# When entering data in a cell, use formula to change other cell from another workbook

Tags: excel, formula

I'm losing my mind at the moment. Let's imagine I have a workbook called "Stock" and in A1 cell I have the value "10".

I have another workbook called "List". What I want to happen is that when the user enters a value in A1 cell of "List", it will subtract that value from "Stock"'s A1 cell.

Any ideas? I've tried with data validation and cross reference the workbooks by using names but I need to define the formula in the "List" workbook because there can be multiple lists using the same stock.

Important: I really need to have two separate workbooks.

Comment: While there is some kind of "iterative formula" way to do this in a VERY limited way (wb has to be open and the value needs to be "changed" etc.). The only way to do it "useable" would be VBA.

Comment: I'm kind of a noob at VBA. Is there any sample you can provide or any website I can get some hints to make it work?

Comment: You would need [`Worksheet_Change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) to trigger the "start"... and the rest can be done via recording. Just hit the "record macro" button, then go to the other workbook and change a cell. Stop recording and check how the code is looking. Most of it should be self explaining. also there are countless "tutorials" out there... just use any search engine ;)

Comment: Thank you :) I'm starting to make it work.